# Unable to sign in to web application after registering user in azure b2c through magic link flow with id token generated successfully

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am working on azure b2c magic link workflow https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite .I am able to generate id_token by following the steps mentioned in the above link but I am unable to sign into web application. The url in the browser stays like https://yourdomain.com/home/landing#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1XXXX...... but doesnt log me in and neither access token is generated. In console its says Redirect success:null. For the front end I am using Angular with msal.js library for handling authentication.
Please kindly let me know whether do I need to make any changes in Angular's msal.js file in order to support magic link flow or do I need to add code in backend to handle the url. I am using .net core web api in the back end. User is created successfully in b2c directory.
All the required policies are added in the azure B2C and certificate is added with private key.
I have read that magic link gives response as id_token, but what to do next once id_token is generated as I am not able to proceed with successful signup and landing on homepage.

id token hint is generated and link to register is sent via email to the people. User is registered successfully in b2c directory but url stays like https://yourdomain.com/home/landing#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1XXXX...... and staruct at this url with no redirection to the web applications home page